# check for TCP packet : Ryu - Python

Tags: python, sdn, ryu

Within a python application for an SDN controller (Ryu), how can I check if a packet in, is a TCP SYN, or SYN-ACK, in order to count these packets?

```
*if packet in is TCP*
self.total_packets += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this specific library, have you tried looking into the lib.packet.tcp module? I think that the method you need is `has_flags()`.

From https://github.com/faucetsdn/ryu/blob/master/ryu/lib/packet/tcp.py there is an example:

```
>>> pkt = tcp.tcp(bits=(tcp.TCP_SYN | tcp.TCP_ACK))
>>> pkt.has_flags(tcp.TCP_SYN, tcp.TCP_ACK)
    True
```

EDIT:

If a function returns a boolean, it can be used in an if as the condition:

```
if pkt.has_flags(tcp.TCP_SYN) or pkt.has_flags(tcp.TCP_SYN, tcp.TCP_ACK):
    self.total_packets += 1
```

Testing just for the SYN flag should also match both SYN and SYN-ACK packets.

```
if pkt.has_flags(tcp.TCP_SYN):
    self.total_packets += 1
```

Comment: thanks, i seen that myself, should this not be in an if statement though?

Comment: would you mind if i contacted you directly re SDN application? (pm/email)